# Express not receiving POST content

Tags: node.js, express, elm

Need some help debugging the following situation. I am using some javascript code that sends data to a server using `XMLHttpRequest()`

It ends with `req.send` of this string `"{ "xxxxsortBy": "xxxxxcoolness", "take": 10 }"`. (This is from the Elm Http.post method in practise.)

I'm running express with

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: true}));
```

Curl commands seem to work as do some other Post commands from older code, but when I log out `req.body` all I get is `{}`.

I would welcome some help trying to debug this situation - i.e. to get `req.body` to include the content posted. (e.g. `curl --data "data=this is a text" http://localhost:5000/tcx` does get picked up properly)

Below is part of the `req` that I receive on the server side.

[image]

Comment: You're sending `text\plain` but probably should send `form-url-encoded`

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin In the long run I want to send a string of xml for my server to convert into json. Does that change anything

Comment: Nope, you will just send something like `xml=<somexml>...&anotherfield=blah` with the same content type and return json

Comment: I am getting some success with setting the headers on the client side manually `req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` but not with `form-url-encoded`

Comment: Yeah, I meant `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` :)